# Using VBA To Add Specific Cells In A Row Depending On The Value Of A Specific Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum cells within a row based on the period. So for instance in period 4 I would some cells B2,C2,D2,E2,and F2. I need this "if this then sum this" function to run for all rows that have data entered. As I can have over 200,000 rows, using an excel formula doesn't work. The output of the summing would be the corresponding cell in column O. Below is a shortened version of my code (I didn't figure I needed to post all 12 periods).

When I run the code I get 'Range' of object'_Global' failed and it highlights where I specified the range for Chicken. Also if anyone knows a cleaner way to do this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
Sub AddRowsBySelectedPeriodMacro()
    Sheets("Blah").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Period As Long, Chicken As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Period = Range("P2")

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Period = "1" Then
            Chicken = Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 3).Value

        ElseIf Period = "2" Then
            Chicken = Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 3).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value

        Else: Period = "12"
            Chicken = Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 3).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value + Cells(i, 5).Value + Cells(i, 6).Value + Cells(i, 7).Value + Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value + Cells(i, 10).Value + Cells(i, 11).Value + Cells(i, 12).Value + Cells(i, 13).Value + Cells(i, 14).Value

        End If

        Range("02:O").Value = Chicken

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Who needs a chicken?**

The range that you want to sum is on row i starting from column 2 to column2 + Period.  We can define that range like this `Range.Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2 + Period))` and sum that range like `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2 + Period)))`.

```
Sub AddRowsBySelectedPeriodMacro()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Period As Long
    With Sheets("Blah")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Period = .Range("P2")

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            .Range("O" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 2 + Period)))

        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: LOL at your first line!  (BTW - the "ActiveSheet." when calculating LastRow should be replaced with just ".", as Sheets("Blah") may no longer be the active sheet.)

Comment: Thanks man!!  I also left the chicken in the declaration pot.

Answer (score 0):

**using an excel formula doesn't work**

If I read your scenario correctly, yes it does.

If `P2` holds the period, any number, 1-12, and the formula:
`=SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,0,1,$P$2+1))` is in P4, with data in B4:N4, you will get the results you want.

You can then drag down the cells.

To speak directly to your question, the piece of code `Range("O2:O").Value = Chicken` needs to be written `Range("O" & i).Value = Chicken`

Comment: Thanks Scott, that fixed my issue. I should have been more specific when I said it won't work in excel. I'm working with around 250,000 rows. With that much data, trying to do the formula in each corresponding cell freezes up and crashes excel. But your fix works great!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of your code would be:

```
Sub AddRowsBySelectedPeriodMacro()
Sheets("Blah").Select
  Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Period As Long, Chicken As Long
  Dim m As Integer
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  Period = Range("P2")

  For i = 2 To LastRow
      Chicken = 0
      For m = 1 to Period
          Chicken = Chicken + Cells(i, m + 1).Value
      Next m

      Range("O" & i).Value = Chicken

 Next i

End Sub
```